# Passing cookies from WebBrowser control to htmlAgilityPack WebClient()

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

My form has a WebBrowser control on it that the user will use to navigate to and login to a website, I then wish to use the HAP so I can use XPath queries to fetch data. Ordinarily of course, the WebClient() session would attempt a loginless session with the same website, thereby not exposing the data I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
using SimpleBrowser;
using System.Net;

var browser = new Browser();
browser.Cookies.Add(new Cookie("Name", "Value", "Path", "Domain"));
```